# Counting the number of rows in pandas dataframe yielding different results

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a csv file into dataframe, then I tried counting the number of rows in a data frame but I got different results. Here is my code

```
data_df = pd.read_csv(data_path, header=0)
print(len(data_df.index)) # => 19695182

data_df_grouped = data_df.groupby(["SiteNumber", "WeekNumber", "PG"]).count()

data_df_grouped #-> This will print out the dataframe in jupyter notebook... I got:
```

[image]

But then I added:

```
data_df_grouped.sum()    # And I got:
```

[image]

Therefore, I can clearly see that the number of rows don't match. What could be the reason?

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Maybe some rows containing `0` or `NaN`?

Comment: Rather than `sum` and the full dataframe, try: `print(data_df_grouped.info())` and `print(data_df_grouped.describe())`

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out that I have duplicate rows in my dataframe, consequently, the `count` followed by the `sum` above yielded to having 19695182 rows. Additionally, printing out `len(data_df_grouped.index)` will yield 19573194 rows, thus, the `data_df_grouped.index` will return the unique row indexes.

```
data_df2 = data_df.drop_duplicates()
data_df2    # yielded: a dataframe with 19573194 rows × 12 columns which is what we want
```